# Showing Xamarin.mac not upto date in cocoa app

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I recently shifted from Windows to Mac. I want to create a project similar to a Windows Forms app in my Mac. So I used cocoa for it. But when I try to build the project it shows this error:

> Error MM0074: Xamarin.Mac 9.0.0 does not support a deployment target of 13.1 for macOS (the maximum is 13.0).

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: lower your deployment target to 13.0

Comment: how can i lower my deployment target?

Comment: look at the Android section of the project properties